# Does a nandroid backup contain the hboot?

Tags: htc-desire, bootloader, nandroid

If I restore a nandroid backup will it restore the hboot and the corresponding partition tables?

I'm on bravo-stock hboot now and I want to try the CM7 hboot. Will I be able to switch back to stock hboot just restoring a nandroid or do I need to flash the stock hboot first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, ClockworkMod (and other custom recoveries) do not backup your bootloader. You can physically look at your backup directory to verify this, but I have never seen a custom recovery that included a bootloader in the backups. What you typically get is:

- Boot partition
- System partition
- Data partition (also `/sdcard/.android_secure` depending on the recovery/version)
- sdext (if you have it)
- WiMAX partition (if you have it)

[The general rule](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20115564&postcount=12) is to make sure you have the correct HBOOT version before you restore a nandroid backup, and you'd have to flash it separately.